# How to write OOP in PHP

Tags: php

Can anybody help is this code can be called OOP design. How to Create a class in PHP which shows that is OOP design.

I'm trying to create a simple example class before I start implementing the following into my projects and I would like to know if there is something I could/should improve. I will be very glad if someone gives me some input of how am I doing now.

This is simple class which is sorting associative array columns. Can anybody write simple class regarding sorting associative array. It can be anything just should follow OOP design pattern.

Thanks in advance for help.

```
<?php


interface PassangerBoardingInterface 
{

        public function ArrageBoardingTicket(string $from, string $to, string $instruction) ;

        public function GetEmbededHTMlTemplate ( $template, $regrex);
}

class PassengerBoardingSorterOOP implements PassangerBoardingInterface
{


        // Boarding list 
        public $boardingList;

        // Journey start message 
        public $startMessage;

        // End message 
        public $endMessage;

        // Get Template 
        public $getTemplate;


        public function __construct(array $boardingList ) 
        {
            $this->boardingList = $boardingList;
        }

        public function ArrageBoardingTicket(string $from, string $to , string $instruction)
        {
            foreach($this->boardingList as $boardingList)
            {

                usort($this->boardingList, function ($a, $b) use ($to, $from){

                      return ($a[$to] === $b[$from] ) ? 0 : 1;
                });
            }


                // Defining index 
            $i = 0;

            $coutboarding = count($this->boardingList);

            // Appending data to start index 
            $this->boardingList[0][$instruction] = $this->startMessage;

            // Appending string to end column 
            $this->boardingList[$coutboarding - 1 ][$instruction] = $this->endMessage;


        }

        public function GetEmbededHTMlTemplate($template, $regrex)
        {
            $result = '';

            /* Loop each data */
            for($j = 0; $j < count($this->boardingList); $j++)
            {
            /* Get the template  */

            $output = $template;
            /* where indexs matches in template  */
            foreach($this->boardingList[$j] as $key => $value)
            {
                $reg = str_replace('(.*?)',$key, $regrex);

                /* Check with regular expression */
                if(preg_match($reg,$template))
                {
                    /* Replace with */
                    $output = preg_replace($reg,$value,$output);


                }           

            }

             $result .= $output;
        }
            $this->getTemplate = $result;

    }
}
```

==============================

## I am using below structure

```
//My array of information
$cards   = [    
            [
                "from" => "Barcelona", 
                "to" =>  "New York", 
                "instruction" => "", 
                'time' => '2018-02-02 20:05',
                'transport' => 'Flight' , 
                'transportno' => 'B33',
                'seatno' => 'Y15'
            ], 

            [
                "from"=> "Barcelona", 
                "to" => "Gerona", 
                "instruction" => "", 
                'time' => '2018-02-02 20:05', 
                'transport' => 'Bus' , 
                'transportno' => 'M31, M32, M33','seatno' => 'Any'
            ], // 1

            [
                "from" => "Madrid",    
                "to" => "Barcelona", 
                "instruction" => "", 
                'time' => '2018-02-02 20:05', 
                'transport' => 'Bus' , 
                'transportno' => 'M31, M32, M33',
                'seatno' => 'Any'
            ],

            ["from" => "New York",    
            "to" => "Stockholm", 
            "instruction" => "", 
            'time' => '2018-02-02 20:05', 'transport' => 'Flight' , 
            'transportno' => 'M31, M32, M33','seatno' => 'Any'
            ], // 0

            [
                "from" => "Gerona",    
                "to" => "Barcelona", 
                "instruction" => "", 
                'time' => '2018-02-02 20:05', 
                'transport' => 'Bus' , 
                'transportno' => 'M31, M32, M33',
                'seatno' => 'Any'
            ], // 2
    ];

    $obj = new PassengerBoardingSorterOOP($cards);

    $obj->startMessage = 'Your journey start from here ';

    // End message 
    $obj->endMessage = 'Your journey ends here';

    $obj->ArrageBoardingTicket('from', 'to', 'instruction');

    // Form a template so you can get template list 
    $template = '<li class="list-group-item">{{&instruction}}Take {{&transport}} From {{&from}} To {{&to}},
     {{&transport}} No  {{&transportno}}, {{&transport}} Departure Date {{&time}}. Seat Number {{&seatno}}.</li>';
    $regrex = '/{{&(.*?)}}/';

    $obj->GetEmbededHTMlTemplate($template, $regrex);

    echo $obj->getTemplate;
```

Comment: That isn't OOP - that is just putting functions inside classes

Comment: Encapsulation 
Inheritance 
Polymorphism I got the ideas about but how we can write above code as OOP desing. Is that required that all codes should be OOP.

Comment: No - you don't got the ideas. You only know the tools. The thing is, you have to use them and know when to use them. OOP is not just to use inheritance and polymorphism. OOP is about structure your data and logic in objects. Don't mix them and keep them in responsible units - and a lot more, but explaining them all is the task of books and tutorials

Comment: Thanks any way. You mean new PassengerBoardingSorterOOP( string $startMessage, string $endMessage). If i am not wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you provided violates a few rules for OOP hence can not be considered as such.

It is a representation of objects that interact with each other in order to create your program, instead of scripts that call each other (hope this makes sense).
You have to start thinking how you can represent your problem into objects.

Let's say you have a car to represent in PHP.

You will start to think you can have:

1. A car class;
2. A Wheel class (you car can have 4 wheels);
3. Then you think "But a car is a vehicle and, for example, a bike only have 2 wheels" and then you create your "Vehicle class";
4. Then you enhance your `Car Class` and extend it from `Vehicle`;
5. Now, each `Vehicle` have tyres, but you do not specify how many, that is for each `type` to decide, not the parent class that "abstracts them".

And so on. You quickly see here that to tackle this problem (and we are on the very start) you already have;

1. Abstract Class Vehicle;
2. Car Class (that extends Vehicle);
3. Bike Class (that extends Vehicle);
4. Wheel Class (That can be added to Vehicle types -> Your Car and your Bike);

When you want to move to OOP there are a few rules you need to consider:

1. Encapsulation;
2. Polymorphism;
3. Open/Close implementation;
4. Inheritance;
5. Open Recursion;

You want to restrict your Class objects to only understand "what they are". So a Car does not hold logic for a Bike and vice-versa.

**1. Encapsulation** -> This prevents external code from manipulating or "holding concern" to what happens on the target class internally;

It refers to the use of **private** and **protected** methods;
How the Car class behaves and what it triggers to work in whatever logic you decide a Car should work, is completely hidden for the other classes like Bike. They do not need to know what clicks on each other!

**2. Polymorphism** -> For example, the number of tyres, or even the Tyre types for each Vehicle, it will be different. Therefore you can declare the `Vehicle` can `addTyres` BUT each `Vehicle` type (like `Car` and `Bike`) will implement how to `addTyres` differently (You can limit bikes to have 2 tyres only whilst cars have 4);

**3. Open/Close implementation** -> When you create classes you should think on them as they should be **OPEN** for extension BUT **CLOSED** for modification. This means you can extend their behaviour BUT you should never have to go back and change your object behaviour;

**4. Inheritance** -> Allows your Classes to implement "hierarchy". Think of it as "parent" and "children". What came "First" and what came "after". Like a **Shape** is a parent of a **Circle**. If you announcing your argument, **Shape** is very abstract as it represents anything from **Squares**, **Triangles**, **Circles**, etc. But if you refer to a **Square** you know about it in more detail, like vertices, angles, etc! Shapes represent that but refine nothing towards what type, just what structure should be but not "how it will be";

**5. Open Recursion** -> Classes are able to call each other and even other classes. That is how they interact. Hell they can even have other objects as part of their attributes;

In a very resumed source this is a very BRIEF introduction to OOP!
Once you get the hang of it it is amazing and you will have such a powerful logical code and so organised I swear to you, you will not go back :3

But yeah, this is not enough to even begin telling you OOP! :x Just think of it this way, it is a walk, not a destination :D

PS: A great way to start getting used to OOP is also starting to look at **Design Patterns**

Comment: Hi thank you very much. I have updated code can you check if it's meeting OOP design pattern rules.

Comment: Your `GetEmbededHTMlTemplate` suggests you will have different templates available and they will behave differently. Because of such, you should have a class for each template type and each class should know their template beforehand and know how to parse it. Instead of passing it as a parameter. Also, if it is a `get` method, should not have parameters

Comment: Also, you see how you are introducing the start and end sentence? This should be specific to each class type and not attributed after the class is instantiated but at the creation of the class (**new class**)

Comment: Your Interface sugests the methods you created are going to be used by more classes of the same type (hence creating the interface), dont be afraid of doing it so. Just make sure the methods that go to the interface ARE indeed a common aspect between your classes

Comment: One part i was unable to understand and that is "Also, you see how you are introducing the start and end sentence?" can you please give example. Thanks.

Comment: @user3201528 I am referring to this **$obj->startMessage = 'Your journey start from here ';**